# Maven: `Unknown packaging: bundle` error from a dependency packaging as bundle

Tags: java, maven

I am running `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:copy-dependencies` in my project, and I'm seeing the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:copy-dependencies (default-cli) on project beam-sdks-java-core: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] [ERROR] Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 6, column 16: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.4
[ERROR] [ERROR] Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 6, column 16
```

Looking at Snappy's pom file, it looks like so:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
    <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <description>snappy-java: A fast compression/decompression library</description>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
    <name>snappy-java</name>
    ....
```

Specifically, the `<packaging>bundle</packaging>` line seems to be the problem.

I tried adding the `maven-bundle-plugin` to my own POM file's `<build>` tag, but that won't fix it (and why should it? I'd think that a dependency's config shouldn't affect my pom?)

How do I enable the `maven-bundle-plugin` for my dependencies? Do I need to add it to a specific subsection of my pom that refers to `apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:copy-dependencies`?

Also, for extra info, my Maven version is 3.5.0

Comment: I also have that problem now. But trying to include com.typesafe:config dependency. It has an invalid pom with packang bundle and does not declare the bundle plugin anywhere in the pom. The only thing I can suggest is contact the library author and ask to correct the pom. I am wondering how these guys manage to build the bundle :)

Comment: FYI I created an issue for this https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/issues/255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an issue with snappy-java 1.1.4. Their pom does not include the bundle plugin. However, version 1.1.7 switches to jar packaging.

You can work around this by using maven-dependency-plugin 2.10.

Comment: This still seems to be a problem in 1.1.7.7

Comment: FYI I created an issue for this https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/issues/255

Answer (score 4):

> I tried adding the maven-bundle-plugin to my own POM file's 
> tag, but that won't fix it (and why should it? I'd think that a
> dependency's config shouldn't affect my pom?

And you are right : it is not the `maven-bundle-plugin` as a `dependency` that you need to
add to make the `bundle` package usable in your build.
What you need is adding the `maven-bundle-plugin` as a `plugin` to
enhance the default Maven lifecycle such as :

```
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Include-Resource> 
                     ....
                </Include-Resource>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

You can find the information in the [`apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin`](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).

Comment: This does not seem to have any effect. The problem is that snappy-java does not include the plugin in the pom for 1.1.4